# Angular2 Router - not able to make resetConfig work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to add some configuration to Angular2 `Router` at runtime.

What I am doing is very simple. In the `AppModule` I load the initial configuration of the `Router` as per guidelines:

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,  
    ...
  ],
  providers: [appRoutingProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**appRoutes   --  app.routes.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: PocWelcomeComponent },
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];
    
    export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [
    
    ];
    
    export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Then in the `AppComponent` `onInit()` method I add some routes like this

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let routes = this.router.config;
    routes.push({ path: 'function1', component: Function1Component });
    this.router.resetConfig(routes);
  }
  
}
```

When I now try to navigate to function1 with the code `this.router.navigate(['/payment']);` I am routed to the `PageNotFoundComponent`.

On the contrary, if I put the configuration of the path to `function1` in the configuration of `AppModule`, everything works.

I am also using Angular-CLI.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code:

```
let r: Route = {
    path: 'pop',
    component: PopupComponent
};

this.router.resetConfig([r, ...this.router.config]);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. It is not clear to me what's different from my original solution. Is a matter of the position of r in the Routes array? Is that resetConfig requires a new Array to actually change? Thanks in any case

Comment: resetConfig(config: Routes) : void (from the [Router docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html) & [Routes docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html) ).
So Routes is an interface Routes (an array of route configurations), not a simple Array.
"..." is a Typescript Spread Operator [link](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/spread-operator.html)

Comment: OK, I get it. I did not cast my Object to Route. That was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. It is, as you guessed in your comment to the other answer, due to the position of your new route in the array. Since you have your final route as a catch-all this gets used before it makes it to your new route. Namely, this route ...

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

... needs to be at the end in your final route config too. So you have to make sure to add your new route earlier than this one in the array. **Unshifting**, instead of **pushing** is one way to achieve that.

```
    let routes = this.router.config;
    routes.unshift({ path: 'function1', component: Function1Component });
    this.router.resetConfig(routes);
```

... or you can use the method mentioned elsewhere ...

```
this.router.resetConfig([r, ...this.router.config]);
```